# Кнопка не реагирует на текст, содержащийся в нём

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой код HTML, он у меня реагирует на саму кнопку, а на текст содержащийся внутри кнопки почему-то не реагирует:

```js
const box_swipe = $(".touch-side-swipe");
let arrow = document.querySelector('#selectCityMobile > .arrow1');
box_swipe.on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('user_region1') || e.target.classList.contains('user_region1').contains('span')) {
    // клик внутри элемента
    console.log('123');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="user_region1" id="selectCityMobile"><span></span><span class="arrow1">&#8595;</span></button>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ну наверное потому что вот это `e.target.classList.contains('user_region1').contains('span')` рабоать не будет и вывалится `TypeError: e.target.classList.contains(...).contains is not a function` или что-то вроде. И хотелось бы знать что значит: "Кнопка не реагирует на текст, содержащийся в нём", -- и каким образом и почему кнопка должна реагировать на текст.

Comment: @Simon, в кнопке есть текст, и у меня срабатывала функция, только если нажимать на поля кнопки, а не на сам текст, содержащийся в нём.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, исправил, добавив класс в тег **span**:

```
if(e.target.classList.contains('user_region1') || e.target.classList.contains('user-region-text'))
```

```
<button class="user_region1" id="selectCityMobile"><span class="user-region-text"></span><span class="arrow1">&#8595;</span></button>
```